# Issues with Firefox 3.6 & SWFObject 2.2

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, swfobject, firefox3.6

I've searched the net for a solution but still haven't found one yet.

I'm on Mac OSX and I use FlashBuilder. I try to publish a movie with the values of 100% for the width & the height. These are the values I use both in SWFObject and the CSS.

Flash doesn't display in Firefox but displays on Opera, Chrome & Safari. SWFObject test suite displays fine though! I've tried to replicate the test suite settings but it doesn't work :( The only way I can get the movie to display in Firefox is by setting the height value to a fixed pixel size in the  flash content div, which defeats the purpose of using percentage values  in the first place :)

I've tried most recommendations such as putting the script in the head tag as well as a few others but nothing works except setting a fixed height size in the CSS.

Help would be most appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer!!! 
For some reason, In Firefox only ( not in Chrome, Opera or Safari , being on OSX, I haven't tried IE ) there's a conflict between Yahoo CSS grids and SWFObject.

I'm using the Zend Framework , so here's the code I was using:

```
<body>
<div id="doc3">
    <?= $this->layout()->content; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Taking away the doc3 container div solved the problem, although the CSS settings for #doc3 were only a zero margin & padding

Comment: Sorry , I could have written this instead:
<body>
<div id="doc3">
    <div id="flashContent">Alternative Content</div>
</div>
</body>

:)